# Using the Python object graph mapper with Memgraph - what is the aim of specifying the db?

Tags: memgraphdb

What is the aim of specifying the db in the class definition and in the field definition?

```
class Language(Node, index=True, db=db):
    name: str = Field(unique=True, db=db)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `db` parameter in the class and field definitions is used to specify the database where the operations will be performed.
In the `class` definition, `db=db` is used to set the database where the index will be created.
In the `field` definition, `db=db` is used to set the database where the constraints will be enforced.